# Allowing users to volunteer for a task via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

My app is setup where a user owns a task and other user's can volunteer to complete these tasks. My models are setup as so:

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations, foreign_key: :participant_id
  has_many :owned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: :owner_id
end
```

**Participation (Join Table)**

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:interested, :selected]

  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :participant, class_name: "User"
end
```

**Task**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:open, :in_progress, :complete]

  has_many :participations
  has_many :participants, through: :participations, source: :participant
  # Dynamically generates relations such as 'selected_participants'
  Participation.statuses.keys.each do |status|
    has_many "#{status}_participants".to_sym,
    -> { where(participations: { status: status.to_sym }) },
    through: :participations,
    source: :participant
  end

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
end
```

What I would like do is simply allow users to click a button to *volunteer* for a task within that particular task's **show** view.

I can accomplish this with ease inside my rails console:

```
user = User.first
task = Task.first
user.owned_tasks << task

user_2 = User.find(2)
task.participants << user_2
```

Where I get stuck is trying to figure out how to setup the necessary controller code to get this to work. I'm also not sure how/where to create the conditional that checks if a user is already participating in a task `is_participating?`. Does it go in the join mode `Participation` or the `Task` table?

I think I have a vague idea on what the view should look like:

**Task - Show View**

```
<% unless current_user == @task.owner %>
  <div class="volunteer-form">
    <% if current_user.is_participating? %>
        <%= render 'cancel' %>
    <% else %>
        <%= render 'volunteer' %>
    <% end %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

**_volunteer.html.erb:**

```
 <%= form_for(current_user.participations.build(participant_id: current_user), remote: true) do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :participant_id %></div>
    <%= f.submit "Volunteer" %>
 <% end %>
```

**_cancel.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.participations.find_by(participant_id: current_user), html: { method: :delete }, remote: true) do |f| %>
   <%= f.submit "Cancel" %>
<% end %>
```

**JS**

```
// create.js.erb
$(".volunteer-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('tasks/volunteer')) %>");

// destroy.js.erb
$(".volunteer-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('tasks/cancel')) %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

From your view looks like `is_participating?` belongs in the `User` model, it should probably be something along these lines:

```
def is_participating?(task_id)
  participations.where(task_id: task_id).exists?
end
```

As for the controller code you probably want something along these lines:

```
class ParticipationsController
  # Note I assume you have access to current_user here

  def create        
    participation = current_user.participations.create(participation_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    participation = current_user.participations.find(params[:id])
    participation.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end 


  protected 

  def participation_params
    params.require(:participation).permit :task_id
  end
end
```

On **_volunteer.html.erb** (Note that you now have to pass the `task` into the partial):

```
<%= form_for(current_user.participations.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :task_id, value: task.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Volunteer" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In the task's show view I get the error: `undefined local variable or method 'task'`

Comment: It's  probably because you're not passing it to the partial, your show view should look something like these: https://gist.github.com/manmartinez/ca4ff5f3061eb3a271da

Comment: I get the error: `undefined method 'merge' for 1:Fixnum` when I pass this as a parameter for my partial: `<%= render 'volunteer',  :task => @task %>`

Comment: Oh the problem is **_volunteer.html.erb** change the hidden_field to:

`<%= f.hidden_field :task_id, value: task.id %>`

Comment: Was something changed in your updated answer for `volunteer.html.erb`?

Comment: Yeah I changed the hidden field declaration (as in the comment above)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82538/discussion-between-carl-edwards-and-manuel-martinez).